# Mostrar resultado de uma consulta sql by group na página PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Boa noite, esse código funciona exatamente da forma que preciso executando direto no sql, porém como eu faço para ele aparecer em uma página php, tentei diversas coisas, até consegui fazer imprimir porém não aparece certo.

```
SELECT estado, COUNT(*) As Total FROM emailc WHERE status = 1 GROUP BY estado
```

Resultado no SQL:
[image: print sql]

O mais próximo que cheguei do resultado igual ao da imagem foi com esse código:

```
$estados = mysqli_query($conexao,"SELECT * FROM `emailc` where status = 1");

while($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($estados)){

    $nomeEstado = $res['estado'];

    $estadoConta = mysqli_query($conexao,"SELECT COUNT(estado) AS TOTAL FROM emailc WHERE estado LIKE '%$nomeEstado%'");

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($estadoConta)){

            echo '<li>'.utf8_encode($nomeEstado).' <strong>'.$row['TOTAL'].'</strong></li>'.PHP_EOL;
```

Porém repete o estado, mas faz a contagem certa como mostra a imagem abaixo:

[image: resultado no php]

Desde já fico agradecido pela ajuda.

Comment: obviamente  na ultima query é que falta o `status`, isso vai dar difença obviamente. Além disso, em ai um `LIKE` na query, pq não usa o `=` ?

Comment: Adicionando o status o resultado permanece igual, e se eu colocar o = no lugar do like, o resultado fica 0, ele não conta quantas vezes tem a sigla RJ por ex.

Answer (score 0):

---RESOLVIDO---
Vou deixar aqui a solução que encontrei pode dar a luz para alguém.

```
$estados = mysqli_query($conexao,"SELECT * FROM `emailc` where status = 1");
```

$nomeEstado = array();

while($row = $estados->fetch_assoc()) {
$nomeEstado[$row['estado']][] = $row;
}
foreach($nomeEstado as $estado => $values){
$estadoConta = mysqli_query($conexao,"SELECT COUNT(estado) AS TOTAL FROM emailc WHERE estado = '$estado'");

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($estadoConta)){

        echo '<li>'.utf8_encode($estado).' <strong>'.$row['TOTAL'].'</strong></li>'.PHP_EOL;
```

}}

Resultado:
[image: funcionou]